# Hibernate - One to Many relationship - only id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two classes and relation between is OneToMany. Its working ok, but i would like to save only ID of the user.

Data Class:

```
public class Data {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String phoneName;

@NotEmpty
private String phoneId;

@NotEmpty
private String phoneNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User userId;
```

and User Class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;

@NotEmpty
private String userEmail;

@NotEmpty
private String password;
```

When I do query I get also all data of the user:

```
[
 {
  "id": 10,
  "phoneName": "SOME CRAZY NAME",
  "phoneId": "165464646464",
  "phoneNumber": "040435005",
  "userId": {
   "userEmail": "xxx@gmail.com",
   "password": "secret",
   "id": 3
  }
 }
]
```

But I would like to get only id of the user, without email and password. Is there any other way to annotate @OneToMany to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to change how your data is serialized, and simply do not output the userEmail / password. (Perhaps a custom Jackson serializer configuration if that's what you're using). Alternatively if using Spring Data Rest, you can likely write a `Projection` to accomplish something similar.

Comment: @CollinD, yes I am using spring. What do you mean with Projection. I am new to spring and its not familiar to me.

Comment: Are you using `spring-data-rest` to automate CRUD endpoints? Or is this a custom controller you've written?

Comment: yes, automate CRUD endpoints.

Comment: This may be of help then: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/ (SDR docs).

Comment: @CollinD, cant I just use JsonIgnore annotation?

Comment: That would likely work as well, however you'll then have to do some fenaggling in order to EVER display those values.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to name that attribute userId, you want to name it user and keep the whole user object, that's what hibernate does.  Simply dealing in IDs is only if you are doing the database transactions yourself.

So you want to:
1.
Change

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User userId;
```

to

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;
```

You don't need the join column if you follow appropriate conventions (which you should, it will make this a lot easier)

2:

In the user class change

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
```

to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

that way when you want to access the user id you can just use data.user.id

3:

If you really need to hide the username and password (obviously you need to hide the password). Then you need to look into JSON Serialization, there are frameworks that make it easier.  Like Jackson has @JsonView and @JsonIgnore annotations that will help you.  Only use @JsonIgnore on an attribute if it is never needed in the front end.  Otherwise look into how @JsonView works (it's rather simple) and specify which attributes you would like to serialize for each controller that you include the @JsonView annotation

Hope this helps

Comment: You'll either need to write a liquibase script to change the database schema or drop your database and rebuild it with the change in the join column name